# Multiple input with a function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

i'm trying to write a function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters that in our case are supposed to be variables of different types, and gets their values from keyboard

here is the code of function call:

```
int a;
float  b;
char   c;
string d;

getValues(a, b, c, d);
```

Is it possible? I think that it is, help me please

Comment: It is the first time I post something here, the 3 ` in the code are not in the actual code, and same for the last words at the end

Comment: Refer to the linked duplicate that uses [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6OS5updNj)